# VS2017 NodeJS TypeScript Console Project Build Errors With @types

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, typescript-typings

So I started working on a TypeScript project in Visual Studio 2017 community edition. I setup a new NodeJS TypeScript Console project. Everything was going great. I was figuring out little idiosyncrasies in TS. Things would build and I could debug them fine.

I then found out about @types. This was cool, I thought. I can now get intellisense for lodash! I ran:

```
npm install -D @types/lodash
```

It installed and I had all the info right in the ide! Sweet. I made some changes and then went to build and run.

The build failed! About 80 some errors about basic stuff. I thought it was my changes but as I backed them out nothing changed. I then by happenstance uninstalled the @types for lodash. It built fine. Installed it again and it failed.

Note, I also tried saving it to dependencies:

```
npm install -S @types/lodash
```

No go. :(

The same goes for any @types/* that I install.

I don't have a tsconfig.json in my project as it seems like the project itself is setup to pass that configuration. I also assume that MSBuild is handling this somehow. Finally, I must also assume that I have some version of TS 2.x installed with VS 2017.

What gives?

**Other Troubleshooting**

I installed the typescript package globally (hadn't done that, just been compiling from VS2017)

```
npm install -g typescript
```

This installs v2.2.2 but makes no difference when attempting to build from inside VS2017.

**Errors**

[image: Errors from Build]

**Configs**

I added in tsconfig.json to try to exclude @types from the compiler. Now I can't build at all.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "es2015", "es2015.promise" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-stupid-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "my-stupid-project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "Mike"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "backblaze-b2": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "nedb3": "^3.0.0",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Saravana Updated the post with the relevant info. Google searches are yielding little up-to-date results, pre-TS 2.x.

Comment: You can try excluding your`@types` folder from compilation. Try adding `"exclude": ["@types"]` to your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Ok. So that is killing the build in a completely different way. :( I had no tsconfig.json before so I added one. Now all my Promise<...> stuff is throwing errors. Changed the target to "es2016" but still no go. :(

Comment: Try adding `"compilerOptions"."lib": ["es6"]`. This will include types containing  `Promise`.

Comment: No go. Posted config files. This is silly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139714/discussion-between-mike-g-and-saravana).